# Delete unmatched rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, time-limit-exceeded

I'm looking to optimize my for loop to search faster. I've turned off ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents, Calculation, and DisplayStatusBar to speed it up a litte. I have about 10,000 rows to search for in the FAR tab. It works by reading the FAR tab rows and if it matches the master account list ("Account_Range") located in the Input tab, it won't delete the row. It will then update the rows (not shown above). I ran this and it took exactly an hour to run.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithArray()

Dim dontDelete() As Variant
Dim actRange As range
Set actRange = Sheets("Input").range("Account_Range")

dontDelete = actRange

Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim isThere As Boolean

Sheets("FAR").Select

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
    For j = LBound(dontDelete) To UBound(dontDelete)
        If StrComp(range("B" & i), dontDelete(j, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            isThere = True
        End If
    Next j
    If Not isThere Then
        range("B" & i).Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
        isThere = False
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest building a `Dictionary` to hold the `Range("Account_Range")`, then you wouldn't have to loop to find a match, just use `.Exists`. I suspect the longest process is deleting rows and moving up all the remaining rows.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there are several slow items:

1.

- `StrComp(Range("B" & i), dontDelete(j, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0`
- I would use `Range("B" & i).Value2 = dontDelete(j, 1).Value2`

2.

- Like PeterT suggested deleting rows is quite slow, specially when you do it one at the time
- I would hide the rows to keep, and at the end delete all visible rows in one operation

3.

- Another significant performance issue is caused by interacting with the sheet
- You could copy both ranges into 2 separate variants and loop them the same way as ranges

---

Bellow I'm providing a different approach:

- create a new column with a formula that will find all matches from Account_Range
- use AutoFilter to hide the rows you want to keep
- delete all visible rows in one operation

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteRowsFilter()
  Const FAR_ROW1 As Long = 3

  Dim lrInput As Long, lrFAR As Long, lcFAR As Long, lastCell As Range
  Dim srcRng As String, fCell As Range, formulaRng As Range, t As Double

  FastWB
  t = Timer

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FAR")
    Set lastCell = GetMaxCell(.UsedRange)
    lrFAR = lastCell.Row
    lcFAR = lastCell.Column

    'create a new column showing if row should be deleted (value = 0) or not (value > 0)
    Set fCell = .Cells(FAR_ROW1, lcFAR + 1)
    fCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(MATCH(B" & FAR_ROW1 & ",Account_Range,0),0)"

    'fill down the formula to last row
    Set formulaRng = .Range(fCell, .Cells(lrFAR, lcFAR + 1))
    fCell.AutoFill Destination:=formulaRng: .Calculate

    'hide the rows to keep
    formulaRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=0"

    'delete visible rows (not matching values in Account_Range)
    fCell.Offset(1).Resize(lrFAR - FAR_ROW1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .Columns(lcFAR + 1).EntireColumn.Delete 'delet last column (temp formula)
  End With

  Debug.Print "Duration:" & vbTab & Format(Timer - t, "#,##0.0000") & " sec" & vbCrLf
  FastWB False
End Sub
```

---

In my test file I only used 2 columns on each sheet, both with 10,000 rows
 
This version deleted more than 6,000 rows

Total Duration:   **1.9338 sec**

---

I also used 2 helper functions

Turn off visual elements:

```
Public Sub FastWB(Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(opt, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .DisplayAlerts = Not opt
        .DisplayStatusBar = Not opt
        .EnableAnimations = Not opt
        .EnableEvents = Not opt
        .ScreenUpdating = Not opt
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Determine the last row and column:

```
Public Function GetMaxCell(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing) As Range

    'Returns the last cell containing a value, or A1 if Worksheet is empty

    Const NONEMPTY As String = "*"
    Dim lRow As Range, lCol As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Set GetMaxCell = rng.Parent.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        With rng
            Set lRow = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            If Not lRow Is Nothing Then
                Set lCol = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

                Set GetMaxCell = .Parent.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

---